# How to display image after call fileupload.click function from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to asynchronous two functions in jquery first one to open file dialog and the second one is to display image on the ImageBox

here is my code below

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ClientIDMode="static" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Trips.test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function previewFile() {
        var preview = document.querySelector('#<%=ImageBox.ClientID %>');
        var file = document.querySelector('#<%=FileUploadx.ClientID %>').files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function () {
            preview.src = reader.result;
        }

        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
            preview.src = "";
        }
    };

    function clk() {
        document.getElementById('#<%=FileUploadx.ClientID %>').click();
    };

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input id="FileUploadx" runat="server" name="file" hidden="hidden" onchange="previewFile()" type="file" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClientClick="return clk().done(previewFile());" Text="Upload" />
        <asp:Image ID="ImageBox" runat="server" Height="225px" ImageUrl="~/Images/NoUser.jpg" Width="225px" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

but I got this error in console :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
>       at clk

Answer (score 0):

In one case you are using `document.querySelector` whereas in the other case you are requesting it by ID.

You can either move both to the `querySelector`, or drop the `#` when using the `getElementByID` method.

You get this error since there is no element with that ID, (hence it is `null`) and them you attempt to call a function on that value.